# Using a channel to pass message between threads

Tags: multithreading, rust, channel

I need to terminate a loop in a thread in Rust by using (tx, rx) channel in Rust to pass a message to the loop that's running.  I have carefully followed chapters 15 -17 of the online rust book to implement a (tx, rx) channel in Rust to terminate a continuously running loop in a thread, but the message won't get through! I am using ICED for the Gui I'm designing and have modified an online ICED example, and it compiles.

```
use chrono::Utc;
use iced::pure::widget::{Button, Column, Container, Text};
use iced::pure::Sandbox;
use iced::Settings;
use rust_gpiozero::*;
use std::thread;
use std::thread::sleep;
//use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use std::env;
use std::io;
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::process;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::time::Duration;

//fn main() -> Result<(), iced::Error> {
//Counter::run(Settings::default())
//}
fn main() -> Result<(), iced::Error> {
    Counter::run(Settings::default())
}

struct Counter {
    count: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum CounterMessage {
    Increment,
    Decrement,
    Increment2,
    Decrement2,
    Flash1,
    Stop,
}

impl Sandbox for Counter {
    type Message = CounterMessage;

    fn new() -> Self {
        Counter { count: 0 }
    }

    fn title(&self) -> String {
        String::from("Counter app")
    }

    fn update(&mut self, message: Self::Message) {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
        //let _val = String::from("hi");
        match message {
            CounterMessage::Increment => self.count += 1,
            CounterMessage::Decrement => self.count -= 1,
            CounterMessage::Increment2 => self.count += 2,
            CounterMessage::Decrement2 => self.count -= 2,
            CounterMessage::Flash1 => {
                thread::spawn(move || loop {
                    let led = LED::new(17);
                    led.on();
                    sleep(Duration::from_millis(500));
                    led.off();
                    sleep(Duration::from_millis(500));
                    //let r1 = rx.recv().unwrap();
                    //let r1 = rx.recv();
                    match rx.recv() {
                        Ok(_) => {
                            break;
                        }
                        Err(_) => {
                            println!("error!")
                        }
                    }
                    continue;
                    //}
                });
            }

            CounterMessage::Stop => {
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    let _val = String::from("hi");
                    tx.send(_val);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    fn view(&self) -> iced::pure::Element<Self::Message> {
        let label = Text::new(format!("Count: {}", self.count));
        let incr = Button::new("Increment").on_press(CounterMessage::Increment);
        let decr = Button::new("Decrement").on_press(CounterMessage::Decrement);
        let incr2 = Button::new("Increment+2").on_press(CounterMessage::Increment2);
        let decr2 = Button::new("Decrement-2").on_press(CounterMessage::Decrement2);
        let flash1 = Button::new("FLASH1").on_press(CounterMessage::Flash1);
        let stop = Button::new("STOP FLASH!").on_press(CounterMessage::Stop);

        let col = Column::new()
            .push(incr)
            .push(label)
            .push(decr)
            .push(incr2)
            .push(decr2)
            .push(flash1)
            .push(stop);
        Container::new(col)
            .center_x()
            .center_y()
            .width(iced::Length::Fill)
            .height(iced::Length::Fill)
            .into()
    }
}
```

Comment: System.Reactive refers to the Reactive Extensions for .NET, also known as Rx. Rx provides developers with a reactive programming model over the generic IObservable<T> interface, as opposed to the traditional imperative programming model or the other reactive programming models that rely strictly on .NET Events or specific APIs.

Comment: Thanks but need help on why my implementation of (tx, rx) mpsc::channel isn't working!!

Comment: It appears there's a bug with the std::sync::mpsc crate. I'm trying out the crossbeam-channel crate right now, but there seems to be a similar issue with that!

Comment: I removed the `[system.reative]`. I can't help you as I don't know rust.

Comment: This is not a bug in std (and you're very unlikely to run into such bugs while you're a beginner).

Answer (score 1):

Every time `update()` is called, it creates a new channel. The channels of the message `Flash1` and of the message `Stop` are *just not the same channel*. When you send into the channel of `Stop`, the channel of `Flash1` won't receive the message, because they're not connected. The sender part of `Flash1` is dropped when we exit `update()` and the channel is closed, and the receiver part of `Stop` is also dropped and the channel is closed.

You can store the channel as a field in `Counter`, so it will be the same channel. One possibility, for example, is to store `Option<Sender>`, assign to it when the message `Flash1` is called, and send into it when the message `Stop` is called.

Comment: Thanks Chayim, you are quite clearly a lot more experienced with this than myself. I tired to get around the problem using an Arc and Mutex, but that didn't work either, I would assume from what you have just taught me, for the same reason. It never occurred to me that the channel is dropped each time update() is called. You have helped me immensely to get my head around this!